# getline(param1,param2,param3) usage in c++ ,linux

Tags: c++, linux, delimiter, getline

...may be so simple question,but am going to write a simple c++ code to parse a string using a delimiter,i want the delimiter to contain multiple spaces(actually one or more space). My question is,is it possible to do that way? my sample code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

        string str="HELLO     THIS IS    888and777";

        char buf[1000];
        getline(buf, 1000);
        string str(buf);

        stringstream stream(buf);
        string toStr;

        getline(stream, toStr,'      ');//here the delimiter is six spaces
        string str1=tostr;

        getline(stream, toStr,'  ');//here the delimiter is two spaces
        string str2=tostr;

        getline(stream, toStr,'   ');//here the delimiter is three spaces
        string str3=tostr;

        cout<<str1<<"\t"<<str2<<"\t"<<str3<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

but,i cant use a delimiter of multiple chars. any idea please.
i get the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’
error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘size_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’
```

Comment: You cannot use `getline` for that. You also cannot use more (or less) than one character between single quotes. `'      '` will get you fired faster than you can say "implementation-defined behavior".

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter used by `std::getline()` is purely an individual character. To accept a string would require a non-trivial algorithm to guarantee suitable performance. In addition, the entities defined using `'x'` normally need to result in an individual `char`.

For the example I think the easiest approach is to simply tokenize the string directly:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<std::string, std::string::size_type>
get_token(std::string const& value, std::string::size_type pos, std::string const& delimiter)
{
    if (pos == value.npos) {
        return std::make_pair(std::string(), pos);
    }
    std::string::size_type end(value.find(delimiter, pos));
    return end == value.npos
        ? std::make_pair(value.substr(pos), end)
        : std::make_pair(value.substr(pos, end - pos), end + delimiter.size());
}
int main()
{
    std::string str("HELLO      THIS IS    888and777");
    std::string str1, str2, str3;
    std::string::size_type pos(0);
    std::tie(str1, pos) = get_token(str, pos, "      ");
    std::tie(str2, pos) = get_token(str, pos, "  ");
    std::tie(str3, pos) = get_token(str, pos, "   ");

    std::cout << "str1='" << str1 << "' str2='" << str2 << "' str3='" << str3 << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: hay,Dietmar Kuhl, a have checked the above code,but it seems it doesn't work.do i have any library to support the std::tie ?? i got the following error:                                                error: ‘tie’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: `std::tie()` comes from `<tuple>`. If you have `<tuple>` you should have `std::tie()` and to get it you'll need to compile at least with C++11. If you don't have it, you can just capture the returned pair and distribute the parameters or change `get_token()` to, .e.g., return the `std::string` and take a reference to the position, instead.